# Remove duplicates items from arraylist and hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an arraylist with the name of who pay something, and another arraylist with the cost of each payment. For example:

- nameArray = Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo, Raul, Raul, Lorenzo, Nicola
- priceArray = 24, 12, 22, 18, 5, 8, 1

I need to sum the cost of each person. So the array must become:

- nameArray = Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo
- price Array = 25, 35, 30

  And then, ordering the array by price, so:
- nameArray = Raul, Lorenzo, Nicola
- priceArray = 35, 30, 25

I'm using a Map, but the problem now is that I see multiple times the name of each person and each payment with the sum.
That's the code:

```
public void bubble_sort(ArrayList<String> nameArray, ArrayList<BigDecimal> priceArray) {
    Map<String, BigDecimal> totals = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size(); ++i) {
        String name = nameArray.get(i);
        BigDecimal price = priceArray.get(i);

        BigDecimal total = totals.get(name);

        if (total != null) {
            totals.put(name, total.add(price));
        } else {
            totals.put(name, price);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
        nameArray.add(entry.getKey());
        priceArray.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < priceArray.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (priceArray.get(j).compareTo(priceArray.get(j + 1)) < 0) {
                BigDecimal tempPrice = priceArray.get(j);
                String tempName = nameArray.get(j);
                priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j + 1));
                nameArray.set(j, nameArray.get(j + 1));
                priceArray.set(j + 1, tempPrice);
                nameArray.set(j + 1, tempName);
            }

        }

    }
    Log.v("New nameArray", nameArray.toString());
    Log.v("New priceArray", priceArray.toString());

}
```

That's the output of the log:

```
New nameArray: [Nico, Nico, Raul, Nico, Raul, Lorenzo, Lorenzo, Raul]
New priceArray: [43.50, 25.50, 18.98, 18.00, 16.98, 9.50, 9.50, 2.00]
```

Nico paid 18.00 + 25.50 = 43.50, Raul 16.98 +2 = 18.98 and lorenzo 9.50.
The name and the price were insert by the user dinamically.

I need to display the array like this:

- nameArray: Nico, Raul, Lorenzo
- priceArray: 43.50, 16.98, 9.50

Comment: Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(nameArray);
or simply take nameArray as Set, set auto remove duplicate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the entries of the `Map` to the original `List`s. You should clear them first:

```
nameArray.clear();
priceArray.clear();
for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
    nameArray.add(entry.getKey());
    priceArray.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Or, if you don't want to overwrite the original `List`s, you should create new `ArrayList`s.

Comment: Thank you man, I already solved it with this code: while(contLoop < nameArray.size()) {
            for (int j = contLoop; j < nameArray.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (nameArray.get(contLoop).equals(nameArray.get(j + 1))) {
                    nameArray.remove(j + 1);
                    priceArray.remove(j+1);
                }
            }
            contLoop++;
        }  which remove the duplicates of each array, but with your code, clearing the array, it's easier and I write less code! Thanks again man!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to implement a `Set<String>` as a `LinkedHashSet<String>()` to preserve insert order. This will insure uniqueness in your set.

Sets check `hashCode()` and the accompanying `equals()`. Items are considered to be equal if their `hashCode()` are their same.

If you implement your own class you can override `hashCode()` and `equals()` to check for uniqueness as well.