# Map and arraylist, add "0" if index is getEntry() is null

Tags: java, android

I have 2 array...1 with the name of the person who pay something and another one with the price of each payment. If a person didn't buy anything, the arrayPrice with the same index of the nameArray at the "name" position, is empty. How can I set a default value to "0" --> big decimal , if the entry is null?
That's my code that fill the array with only [0], even if I have 1 person with 1 payment:

```
db.collection("users").document(email).collection("Group").document(groupName)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                      // Getting all the partecipants of a group
                        String[] values = (String.valueOf(document.get("partecipant")).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split(","));
                        for(String value : values){
                            nameArray.add(value);
                        }
                        Log.v("nameArraydownloaded", nameArray.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(email).collection("Group").document(groupName);

    docRef.collection("Payments")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                        //Extracting payment description from each document


                        cont += 1;
                        //Extracting cost and who payed from each document

                        price = document.getString("cost");
                        priceFloat += Float.parseFloat(price);
                        priceArray.add(new BigDecimal(price));
                        name = document.getString("paid by");
                        nameArray.add(name);

                    }

                    numberOfPaymentTV.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
                    totalCost.setText(decimalFormat.format(priceFloat) + "€");
                    cpp = decimalFormat.format(priceFloat / Float.parseFloat(num_partecipants));
                    costPerPerson.setText(cpp + "€");


                    while(priceArray.size() < nameArray.size()){
                        priceArray.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
                    }
                    if (nameArray.size() > 0) {
                        // Manipulate the arrays
                        Map<String, BigDecimal> totals = new HashMap<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size(); ++i) {
                            String name = nameArray.get(i);

                            BigDecimal price = priceArray.get(i);
                            BigDecimal total = totals.get(name);

                            if (total != null) {
                                totals.put(name, total.add(price));
                            } else {
                                totals.put(name, price);
                            }
                        }
                        nameArray.clear();
                        priceArray.clear();
                        // Adding single name and price value for each partecipant
                        for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
                            nameArray.add(entry.getKey());
                            priceArray.add(entry.getValue());

                        }
                        // Order the array by descending price
                        for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size(); i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < priceArray.size() - 1; j++) {
                                if (priceArray.get(j).compareTo(priceArray.get(j + 1)) < 0) {
                                    BigDecimal tempPrice = priceArray.get(j);
                                    String tempName = nameArray.get(j);
                                    priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j + 1));
                                    nameArray.set(j, nameArray.get(j + 1));
                                    priceArray.set(j + 1, tempPrice);
                                    nameArray.set(j + 1, tempName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Log.v("priceArray", priceArray.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size() - 1; i++) {
                            if (BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(cpp.replace(",", "."))).subtract(priceArray.get(i)).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
                                receiverArray.add(nameArray.get(i));

                            }

                        }


                        for (int i = 1; i < nameArray.size(); i++) {

                            if (BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(cpp.replace(",", "."))).subtract(priceArray.get(i)).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {

                                debtorArray.add(nameArray.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        if (receiverArray.size() > debtorArray.size()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size() - 1; i++) {
                                differenceArray.add(priceArray.get(i).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(cpp.replace(",", ".")))).abs());

                            }
                        } else {
                            for (int i = 1; i < nameArray.size(); i++) {
                                differenceArray.add(priceArray.get(i).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(cpp.replace(",", ".")))).abs());
                            }
                        }

                        if (!receiverArray.isEmpty() && !debtorArray.isEmpty()) {
                            while (receiverArray.size() < debtorArray.size()) {
                                receiverArray.add(receiverArray.get(receiverArray.size() - 1));
                            }
                            while (debtorArray.size() < receiverArray.size()) {
                                debtorArray.add(debtorArray.get(debtorArray.size() - 1));
                            }
                        }
                        Log.v("recArray", receiverArray.toString());
                        Log.v("debArray", debtorArray.toString());
                        Log.v("difArray", differenceArray.toString());

                        customAdapter = new ReportAdapter(getActivity(), debtorArray, receiverArray, differenceArray);
                        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                    }
                }
```

The array with this code is [14.00], but there are 3 person in the name array, and I need the priceArray to be: [14.00, 0, 0]
How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is `Map#compute`.

Comment: This looks like a follow-up question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53706649/8298909 . Are you saying that the original `priceArray` can have `null` elements in it?

Comment: @BenP. No, the price Array contains the total amount spent by everyone. If a partecipants didn't buy anything, I Need to set the default amount to 0, but now my priceArray increase the size only if a partecipants buy something

Comment: In your original question, you say `nameArray = Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo, Raul, Raul, Lorenzo, Nicola` and `priceArray = 24, 12, 22, 18, 5, 8, 1`. What would it look like if Nicola didn't spend anything?

Comment: @BenP. Yes but know I changed my code..the nameArray contains each partecipants of a group, even if the didn't buy anything. Then, at the begin the priceArray Is the same you wrote in your comment. But then I sum the payment of each partecipants so the price Array became "25,35,30" and the nameArray "nicola,Raul,Lorenzo". Let's suppose that now I have the nameArray with "Nicola,Raul, Lorenzo' and Lorenzo didn't buy anything, this i the new situation : nameArray "Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo", priceArray "25,35", but I want to Be 25,35,0

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include the setup for the situation you're talking about. You keep talking about how there can be a name without a price; show what that looks like.

Comment: @BenP. Yes, now I'm not at home..I'll take a better look at my code and my question later and I'll update them

Comment: Cool. Drop a comment in here when you do the edit and I'll check it out.

Comment: @BenP. yeah, you were right, I put in nameArray only the participants that have at least 1 payment. Instead, I have to put all the partecipants of the group...I'll try to fix this error and then I update my question with new code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185146/discussion-between-nicola-and-ben-p).

Answer (score 0):

You need `map.getOrDefault("key", <defaultValue>)` .

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or
>   defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.